# Javascript : problem in html page rendering

Tags: javascript

when i am rendering a page I have a confirm button that pops up before the page is fully rendered . now if i delay in choosing an option from the confirm box my page is left half rendered and if i select an option from the confirm box quickly the page is fully rendered.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Why interrupt the page load, may i ask?

Answer (score 0):

Because browsers read web page from top to bottom and execute javascript on the way. You should use < body onload="yourfunction()" > to display your confirm box after page loaded completely. Or you can use jquery .ready function:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: why does it work then when i select an option within 100 secs and not after that?